# Stuck on class issues

Tags: java

So I'm making a java program to keep track of my daily/weekly schedule. I have a class that takes my time. Another that takes the date. A class that lets me make a choice to add events and display them for a week or day. Another class that gets a quick description of what the event is then queues me to get the information from other classes and then display it.

So short way, all things are spread in multiple classes. Time, date, getting event, wanting to add an event and where the event is stored are all apart.

So my question is; how do I pass these values from class to class and keep them saved for when I enter another event efficiently? What sort of data types, functions would be best?

Keeping in mind so many things are separate.

Update:

So I've got more of it working, but I have an array and I need to get the date, time and description of the event to stick to the number of the array:

Example: Work, 2014/1/1, 10:00 as the value of 0 in the array.

How do I get those value to stick to 0 in the array when they're all separate?

Answer (score 0):

View your data structure on how you would view your real life calendar.
E.g. one person could have one calendar - the calendar is made up of days, multiple events can occur on any given day. Events can occur repeatedly, and span given days.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Main Handler class that will keep a reference to all the required information by maintain a reference(a member data/object) to each of the class you require